# How to speed up training for CNN layers fed with T5EncoderModel outputs?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I'm training a series of CNN layers using the outputs of a transformer model, specifically `T5EncoderModel`. I feed sequences into the encoder and feed the outputs to my CNN layers.

My problem is that my training speed is too slow, bottlenecked by each forward pass through the transformer.

Running the encoder in half-precision (i.e., `fp16`) greatly helped, but I am struggling to find anything else that can speed it up even further.

What would be the optimal way to do this?

Comment: You could try using fewer layers.

Comment: Fewer layers in my CNN? Most of the time is spent on the transformer.

Comment: Fewer layers in the transformer. How many are you currently using?